# label invertido Vuetify

Tags: vuetify

Quando copio e colo qualquer código do `vuetify` fica invertido o Label porém no codepen funciona normal. Já tentei definir no Style para personalizar mas não dá certo. pois tem q ajeitar os `fields` também. Como faz para manter o `label` a esquerda?

[Exemplo online](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fgrids%2F)

---

```
<template>
    <v-form v-model="valid">
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="4"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="firstname"
              :rules="nameRules"
              :counter="10"
              label="First name"
              required
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
  
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="4"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="lastname"
              :rules="nameRules"
              :counter="10"
              label="Last name"
              required
              outlined
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
  
          <v-col
            cols="12"
            md="4"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="email"
              :rules="emailRules"
              label="E-mail"
              required
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
</template>
```

> [image: label trocados estão no lado direito, sendo o correto pelo esquerdo]

```
<style scope>
    label{
        left: 0 !important;
        right: auto!important;
    }
    .v-label--active{
        transform: translateY(-25px)translateX(-12px) scale(.75)!important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando a tag  depois de templete, Ele é requerido para toda o app, sem ele não funciona. Segue a documentação para você dar uma olhada:

[Documentação v-app](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/)

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <v-form v-model="valid">
        <v-container>
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" md="4">
                    <v-text-field
                        v-model="firstname"
                        :rules="nameRules"
                        :counter="10"
                        label="First name"
                        required
                    ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12" md="4">
                    <v-text-field
                        v-model="lastname"
                        :rules="nameRules"
                        :counter="10"
                        label="Last name"
                        required
                        outlined
                    ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12" md="4">
                    <v-text-field
                        v-model="email"
                        :rules="emailRules"
                        label="E-mail"
                        required
                    ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-form>
</v-app>
```